# Increment with total not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Look at my codes. Increment with total of score not working.

Well I did not know what exactly would be a good title for this because it is a most peculiar situation or I'm abnormally dumb.

AJAX

```
function incrementValue(id)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num'+id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('num'+id).value = value;
    values = value + value;
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = values;
}
```

My blade

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th class="translate">owowow</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="num0" value="0" class="form-control col-sm-1 translate" name="encouragemen222">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue(0)" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="translate">owowow</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="num1" value="0" class="form-control col-sm-1 translate" name="encourafgemen222">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue(1)" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">Total:
        <span id="sum" class="translate">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: images]

Comment: Could you post the html output from your blade so that we might see what it's actually pulling from the db and inserting into html?

Comment: need to see your actual HTML, it would be easier to debug if you can post that?

Comment: I editted the my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, `value++` will add value on bottom of the function, you better change it to `value += 1;`

```
function incrementValue(id)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num'+id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value += 1;
    document.getElementById('num'+id).value = value;
    var values = parseInt(document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML, 10);
    values = isNaN(values) ? 1 : (values + 1);
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = values;
}
```

Comment: You can try it again.

Comment: What's the phenomenon?